# Serializing multiple tiers of XML elements

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

Let's say I'm trying to create an XML document out of an object. Is this possible using JAXB annotations on a single Food class, or do I need to create inner classes for Cost and Flavor?

I know I can use @XmlElement or @XmlAttribute to set up immediate children of my root element. However, I'm not sure if/how to create the `<cost>` and `<Flavor>` tags as I show here.

```
<Food>
  <cost amt=13.5 unit=USD/>
  <Flavor spicy=5>It tastes good</Flavor>
</Food>


@XmlRootElement("Food")
public class Food {

   private float amount;
   private String units;
   private String flavorType;
   private STring flavorDescription;
}
```

Comment: I think you need inner class for both `cost` and `flavor`

Answer (score 1):

Add a new Java class *Cost*:

```
public class Cost
{
    @XmlAttribute
    double amt;
    @XmlAttribute
    String unit;
 }
```

And exdend class *Food*

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Food {

   private float amount;
   private String units;
   private String flavorType;
   private String flavorDescription;

   private Cost cost;
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use something like this for Flavor class

public class Flavor {

private long spicy;
private String shortDesc;

**@XmlValue**
    public String getShortDesc() {
        return shortDesc;
    }
    public void setShortDesc(String shortDesc) {
        this.shortDesc = shortDesc;
    }
    **@XmlAttribute**
    public Long getSpicy() {
        return spicy;
    }
    public void setSpicy(long spicy) {
        this.spicy= spicy;
    }

}